# Why does training fail when I change the reinforcement learning code and the tensor size and value are the same as before the change?

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I used Pytorch  and fully connected layers to train examples in a 2D environment.

I know it's inefficient to change the structure to CNN in the current code, but I want to change the structure of the layer to CNN for my studies.

But size, values, and structure of the code I changed are exactly the same and not error, but the training is not progressing.

Below is the changed code.

https://github.com/pytorch/tutorials/blob/main/intermediate_source/reinforcement_q_learning.py

This code is the optimize_model function on 337 line, and I changed the following parts

```
state_action_values = self.policy_net(state_batch).gather(1, action_batch)  

print(state_action_values.size()) #torch.Size([128, 1])
```

to

```
state_action_values = []
        for i in range(self.batch_size):
            value = self.policy_net(state_batch[i].unsqueeze(0))
            state_action_values.append(value[0][int(action_batch[i])])
        state_action_values = torch.tensor(state_action_values, dtype=torch.float32, device=self.device, requires_grad=True).unsqueeze(1)

print(state_action_values.size()) #torch.Size([128, 1])
```

and

```
next_state_values = torch.zeros(self.batch_size, device=self.device)
with torch.no_grad():
     next_state_values[non_final_mask] = self.target_net(non_final_next_states).max(1)[0]

print(next_state_values.size()) #torch.Size([128, 1])
```

to

```
next_state_values = torch.zeros(self.batch_size, device=self.device)
with torch.no_grad():
    for i in range(len(non_final_next_states)) :
        if non_final_mask[i]:
            value = self.policy_net(non_final_next_states[i].unsqueeze(0))
            next_state_values[i] = torch.max(value)

print(next_state_values.size()) #torch.Size([128, 1])
```

Do you know how to solve the problem? thx.

Comment: What is "The current code" - yoou are showing excerpts of code that you ahve changed but we cannot know what the rest of the code does. It is unclear what you are doing in terms of datasets you use, how you preprocess them, how you perform your training and so forth

Comment: I've added your point to Body